# How to add \thanks to metropolis theme?

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I want to add \thanks to my titlepage while using the Metropolis theme but in the minimal working example below, nothing happens - just a 1 right next to the author but nothing in the footnote.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio = 169]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\title{Short and snappy title}
% \subtitle{A modern beamer theme}
 \date{\today}
\author{Author~One \and Author~Two\thanks{I acknowledge Thankee One's assistance.}}
\institute{Random Institute}
```

Is there any way to add this footnote in the Metropolis theme? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a normal footnote instead:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio = 169]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\title{Short and snappy title}
% \subtitle{A modern beamer theme}
 \date{\today}
\author{Author~One \and Author~Two\footnote{I acknowledge Thankee One's assistance.}}
\institute{Random Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\vskip-0.1cm
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]